# Criticism of R6RS scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme

I heard many complaints by Schemers about the new R6RS Scheme. What has become worse than in R5RS?

Comment: this is like the definition of 'subjective and argumentative' question. voting to close.

Comment: @Paul: And that bickering (between the R5RS and R6RS camps) has been happening for like 5 years now. It's nothing new. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You should read the [comments](http://www.r6rs.org/ratification/results.html) that the electors have posted with their votes on R6RS ratification. Some of them are very telling.

Obviously, reasonable people can disagree about some of them. Try to read them with an open mind. :-)